# Uncaught Error: Can't find typescript module/class in import statement of .spec.ts

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine, node-modules

I'm unable to run unit test due error "**Uncaught Error: Can't find ./first [F:/MyAppPath/scripts/first.ts] (required by F:/MyAppPath/scripts/first.spec.ts)**"

I have already tried to import through require() and * as but it didn't work. also cursor get naviaget to actual class/file when I press F12 on **FirstModule** of below line.

`import { FirstModule } from "./first";`

below are my codes.

**first.ts**

```
export module FirstModule {
    export class firstClass {
        id:number;
        name:string; 
    }
}
```

**first.spec.ts**

```
import { FirstModule } from "./first";

describe('example test', function () {
  let _first
  beforeEach(() => {
    _first = new FirstModule.firstClass();
  })

  it('module defined', function () {
    expect(_first).toBeDefined();
  });
```

**Logs:**

*Uncaught Error: Can't find ./first [F:/MyAppPath/scripts/first.ts] (required by F:/MyAppPath/scripts/first.spec.ts)
  at node_modules/karma-typescript/src/client/commonjs.js:13*

Comment: is it your `angular`(2.X+) test file?

Comment: No, it is just typescipt and spec files. mot a project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error suggest, `first.ts` file is missing while running `first.spec.ts` through Karma.

Need add below configuration in your `Karma.config.js` file.

```
files: [     
  '*.spec.ts',
  '*.ts' //this thing is missing
]
```

Comment: wow, it's awesome. perfectly work for me. Life saver. Thanks dude